# Modelling the PCB parasitic capacitance in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, transfer-function, transient, frequency-response

I need to simulate the accurate behaviour of my attenuator made of an RC potential divider. Time constants of the top and bottom of my attenuator are matched.

[image]

I noticed that when I inject a square wave into my attenuator I get a very specific distortion. It is my belief it is caused by the frequency dependant parasitic capacitance of my PCB material. As at higher frequencies this parasitic capacitance increases.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have a time-domain behaviour of my attenuator and I want to incorporate this behaviour in my LTSpice simulation.

I would like to be able to simulate this behaviour both in the transient analysis as well as in frequency sweep.
For the frequency sweep, I am thinking about using a voltage-dependent voltage source and S domain transfer function. However unsure how to extract the transfer function out of this plot. I sampled the response of the attenuator using FFT and copied fundamental and the first 5 odd components both frequency and amplitude (I think I should have copied more to get a more meaningful response of the system). However unsure how to incorporate this data into my simulation.
From what I read using the Laplace operator in AC sweep is fine but not in the transient analysis. Is there any other way to incorporate complex behaviour in the time domain without the Laplace operator?

Comment: Can you explain this unusual phenomenon: `As at higher frequencies this parasitic capacitance increases`. I can't speak for LTSpice but, in my simulator the Laplace functions work just fine during transient measurements. Have you actually tried this out?

Comment: From what I gather some PC materials change their parasitic capacitance with the frequency of the passing signal. I am fresh to the subject so not that knowledgeable. Sorry.

Comment: As long as you have a high frequency pole that ensures fall-off towards high frequencies, you can try Laplace, as quirky as they are (they're not always reliable, as you've seen in the manual). But for an influence of the PCB, I'd say it's enough to add parasitic inductances and capacitances, and/or damping, and you will get quite close results. What I see is close to a 2nd order response. Don't forget to accurately add the probe's impedance, too.